# How to explode multple columns to multiple rows and add an additional column, based on exploded ones?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, describes below:

```
|Name|Date|Length|Width|Height|Other_columns...|
|----|----|------|-----|------|----------------|
|foo |bar | 0.5  | 0.6 | 0.7  |................|
```

I need to explode it by columns `Length`, `Width` and `Height`, and create a column `Dimension` which would represent exploded value.

Final dataset should looks like this:

```
|Name|Date|Value|Dimension|
|----|----|-----|---------|
|foo |bar | 0.5 | Length  |
|foo |bar | 0.6 | Width   |
|foo |bar | 0.7 | Height  |
```

I have figured out how to make work the first part of the task, the exploding. These lines of code both work well:

```
val res = params
 .select("Name", "Date", "Length", "Width", "Heigth")
 .withColumn("Value", explode(array("Length", "Width", "Heigth")))
 .drop("Length", "Width", "Heigth")
```

or

```
val res = params.select(col("Name"), col("Date"), explode(array("Length", "Width", "Heigth")).as("Value"))
```

But I don't have a clue how add the `Dimension` column and corresponding values to it.

Will appreciate any help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to first create tuples of the dimension values and labels using a UDF before exploding them:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("foo", "bar", 0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
).toDF("Name", "Date", "Length", "Width", "Height")

def zipDimension = udf(
  (l: Double, w: Double, h: Double) => Seq( (l, "Length"), (w, "Width"), (h, "Height") )
)

val df2 = df.
  withColumn("Temp", explode( zipDimension($"Length", $"Width", $"Height") )).
  select($"Name", $"Date", $"Temp._1".as("Value"), $"Temp._2".as("Dimension"))

df2.show
+----+----+-----+---------+
|Name|Date|Value|Dimension|
+----+----+-----+---------+
| foo| bar|  0.5|   Length|
| foo| bar|  0.6|    Width|
| foo| bar|  0.7|   Height|
+----+----+-----+---------+
```

Comment: You saved me tons of time. Thanks!)

Comment: Glad that it helps.